# Disable .htaccess redirect for internal links does not work - Is caching the problem?

Tags: .htaccess

Assume a french webpage is available under `https://example.com/` and an english version under `https://example.com/en`.

If `https://example.com/` is visited directly (enter the address manually or by some external link) the visitor should be redirected automatically to `https://example.com/en` if `fr` is not included in the `Accept-Language` header.

However, when calling `https://example.com/` from some **internal link**, there should be NO automatic redirect. Otherwise it would not be possible to manually switch from `/en` to the french main page.

I tried so solve this using the following code in `.htaccess`

```
# Check if NOT an internal link. Since it is not possible use environment
# vars on both sides at the same time, construct an string by combining
# HOST + REFERER and then checking if the first part (the host) is contained
# in the second part (the referer)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{HTTP_REFERER} !^([^@]*)@@https?://\1/.*

# Apply to main page only. Do not inlude subpages.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]

# Redirect if FR is not accepted
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} !fr [NC]

# Redirect to english main page
RewriteRule ^$ /en [L,R]
```

The first time I tried this, it worked as expected. However, once I call `https://example.com/` manually and I am redirected to `/en` it does not work anymore.

**Why is this?**

Is it possible that there is some caching involved which simply check "Ok, last call to / was redirected to /en, so just redirect the next calls there as well without checking .htaccess again"? Or is there any other problem with these rules?

The page is running on a shared Server where I cannot access any config files. Is it possible to solve this in .htaccess only?

Comment: There is a general problem with this approach, and that is the unreliability of the referrer. Browser / extensions / firewalls might decide to modify it in an attempt to protect user privacy, or remove it completely. You simply can not base any decisions on it, if you want to be sure it will works for every visitor.

Comment: In addition, and more important here: you say this does not work if you _manually_ call that URL. From reading your question I understand that by this you mean you manually enter that address in your browser's address bar. In such cases no referrer header will get sent at all. For obvious reasons ...